# How to create a database of feature vectors for images?

Tags: database, image, matlab, class, vector

I have a database of around 4 classes each consistent of around 50 images. I created a features vector on Matlab to extract the features I need from each image.

How to create the database of vectors for all the images to then train them per class?

Answer (score 1):

Create a cell array of 50*4 size, where rows corresponds to each image, and columns correspond to each class of the respective image. Check the below pseudo code:

```
N = 50 ;  % number of images 
C = 4 ; % number of classes 
%% loop for each image 
iwant = cell(N,C) ;
for i = 1:N
    %% Extract the features of images,
    iwant{i,1} = rand(10) ;
    iwant{i,2} = rand(5) ;
    iwant{i,3} = rand(6) ;
    iwant{i,4} = rand(11) ;
end
```

Comment: does rand(10) represent that 10 images exist for the first class and 5 images for class 2 and so on?and how did i extract the features using this method?